# Where Jenkins clone GIT repository?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to find out where Jenkins clone the GIT repo but I can't find it.
In my script in Jenkins pipeline I have:

```
    stage('Do something'){
      steps {
        sh '''
            #!/bin/bash
            YAML_FILE="${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/<JENKINS_JOB_NAME>/workspace/GIT_REPO_NAME/path/to/file.yaml"
...
```

However when I am trying to buid it, it can't find it in this path:

```
 Error: open /efsmnt/jobs/<JENKINS_JOB_NAME>/workspace/GIT_REPO_NAME/path/to/file.yaml: no such file or directory
```

I also found that it could be in:

```
20:13:55  Error: open /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/<JENKINS_JOB_NAME>/GIT_REPO_NAME/path/to/file.yaml: no such file or directory
```

but with no luck.

Comment: How do you ‘git clone’? You could run ‘pwd’ there to see which directory it is executed in

Comment: Jenkins uses all kinds of wacky paths. Your best bet is to avoid assuming anything: use `pwd` or `$PWD` to find the *current directory*, which is where the clone has occurred by that point.

Comment: ok, got it in `.` cloned directly to working directory.

Answer (score 1):

The global environment `WORKSPACE` represents the job workspace where your repo will be clone into.

And Jenkins won't create `GIT_REPO_NAME` folder in job workspace when run git clone.

You can try below script

```
sh '''
  pwd
  ls -l
  YAML_FILE="${WORKSPACE}/path/to/file.yaml"
'''
```

Use double quote in case job workspace path includes space when Jenkins job or Jenkins folder name includes space